# XML listview is not refreshing?

Tags: qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, momentics

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the Momentics IDE (native SDK).

I have listview that get its data from an XML file using **XmlDataModel**. The problem is when I try to change an item data, I change the data inside xml file but the problem is that the list in not refreshed with the new data unless I re-enter the page where the list is.

Can any one help me on this ? I will be very thankfull .

Comment: Never use Qt on BB, guess it is Qt 4.8. Have you tried using [XmlDataModel::reload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-xmllistmodel.html#reload-method) ?

Comment: The reload function doesn't exist  in XMLDataModel. What you mean by never using Qt on BB ? but the BB10 is using QML for designing UI.

Comment: I have no idea where to begin. XmlDataModel loads data once. If you change it you need to tell XmlDataModel about it, so try to load again. You could also use like GroupDataModel + DataSource and then update value in GroupDataModel

Comment: I would change to use a DataSource+GroupDataModel, much more flexible. But if you insist on using XmlDataModel then you could try setting source again (perhaps as empty first and then the new xml file) that should trigger a reload.